# Branch A overwriting Master Branch on merging git

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I have a file let's call it File A. I type something on the first line. Then i commit it on the master branch.

Now i make another Branch lets call it BranchA. Now i open file remove what i have written on the first line type something else on the same line and commit it on the BranchA.

Now i `checkout` to the master branch and then merge the BranchA with the master branch. The Merge is completed successfully and when i open the file the line on BranchA has overwritten the line on master Branch.

Why is this happening shouldn't it give me a conflict because i am changing the same line on both the branches and then trying to merge them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario you are describing is expected behaviour.

As far as I understand your question you have a commit graph which could look like this:

```
o---o <- master
     \
      o <- A
```

If you now merge A into *master* git will do a `fast-forward` merge, which effectivly just changes the commit *master* points at.
As there are no further changes on *master* which diverge from *A* there is no need to merge.

---

Now let's assume we have the following commit graph:

```
o---o---o <- master
     \
      o <- A
```

In this case your branches diverge. You have changes on *master* which aren't on *A* and you have changes on *A* which aren't on master. This is a typical situation where a merge is necessary.

You can take a look at the [Basic Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) chapter of the gitpro book which covers all this and more.

Comment: You mean that instead of merging the two commits, git directly moves the commit from other branch to the master branch right ?

Comment: Git doesn't move any commit. In git branches are merely a **reference** on a specific commit. You can even take a look at them if you open a file in `.git/refs/heads`. They are literally a file which contains a the *SHA1* key identifying the commit. Git just changes this reference.

Comment: In git each commit saves a refence on its parent commit (or parent commit**s**, this defines a merge commit). This way your history builds.

Comment: aha so in this case git just moves the reference to commits from BranchA to the master branch ?

Comment: Exactly. Git just changes the reference in *master* to point at the same commit as *A*.